# How to avoid copying values to a separate array?

Tags: c++

I have the following program that computes the "partial sum" of an array. For example, if I input the consecutive integers `1, 1, 1, 1` through `std::cin` my program will calculate the result into an array as `1, 2, 3, 4`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int orig[10], copy[10];
    std::cout << "please enter 10 numbers:" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> orig[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; --k)
        {
            sum += orig[k];
        }
        copy[i] = sum;
    }

    std::cout << "the ascending order is:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << copy[i] << std::endl;
}
```

My problem is that I would like for there to be a way to do this without copying the value into another array. So far I haven't figured out how. As you can see, in the above code I have an integer array named `copy` into which I put the sum into its indicies. I know this can be done using `std::vector` and `partial_sum` but I would rather not use it as it does not allow me to fully understand how this works.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the two nested `for` loops. Move the initialization of `sum` out of the `for` loop to keep track of the `sum` as you iterate over `orig`. The simply overwrite the values in `orig` with `sum` as you go.

In psuedocode:

```
sum = 0
for each index i in array:
  sum += array[i]
  array[i] = sum
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to use `partial_sum`, but here it is in all its simplicity:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    partial_sum(istream_iterator<int>(cin),
                istream_iterator<int>(),
                ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Code [here](http://ideone.com/Dl5SbL).

Comment: I actually used something like this, except it was with a vector: `std::patial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin())` and then I printed it out. But yours seems way better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you print this out in the process without storing it?

```
sum = 0 ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
   sum += orig[ i ] ;
   std::cout << sum << "\n" ;
}
```